# Printing PHP errors with python

Tags: php, python

I'm using the following to run PHP code with python. If the PHP code located in the file.php encounters an error, I can see the error on my terminal, but I want to have the error on the result variable.

How can I catch the error as a string?

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("php /path/file.php", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
result = proc.stdout.read().decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: Maybe read `stderr`

Answer (score 0):

The error messages are usually written to `stderr`, rather than `stdout`. If that is the case, you can get it from the corresponding attribute.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["php", "/path/file.php"],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out = proc.stdout.read().decode("utf-8")
err = proc.stderr.read().decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: This returns: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: @unska Make sure you copied the code correctly. Works fine for me. You probably didn't pass the `stderr` argument.